# Selecting result based on the row itself

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a MySQL table like

```
id  | ref  | c1  | c2  | c3
---------------------------
1   | 3    | x   | y   | z
2   | 2    | a   | b   | c
3   | 1    | p   | q   | r
4   | 3    | m   | n   | o
5   | 2    | j   | k   | l
```

My question is **How can I `SELECT` the `id` and value of either `c1`, `c2` or `c3` based on the value of the column `ref`**

that is,
    for **ref = 1** the value of **c1** will be selected,
    for **ref = 2** the value of **c2** will be selected
and
    for **ref = 3** the value of **c3** will be selected

**Desired Result:**

```
id  | cX 
-----------
1   | z
2   | b
3   | p
4   | o
5   | k
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Hint:  Use a `case` expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `CASE`.

```
SELECT id,
       CASE ref
         WHEN 1 THEN
           c1
         WHEN 2 THEN
           c2
         WHEN 3 THEN
           c3
       END cx
       FROM elbat;
```

Answer (score 1):

use case when

```
select id,case  ref when 1 then c1
when 2 then c2
 when 3 then c3 
  end as cx from table1
```

General case function/expression

```
CASE expression
    WHEN condition1 THEN result1
    WHEN condition2 THEN result2
   ...
    WHEN conditionN THEN resultN
    ELSE result
END
```

Comment: General _expression_.

Comment: It's still not a case _statement_, it's a case _expression_!